# How to find all elements of a collection in an array that matches two conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I've been looking at [this documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find), and I tried to implement it here:

```
customers.find({'name':tenantName,'scripts.author':author},'scripts',function(err,data2){
```

But this doesn't find what I want it to find. and I get back every element of `scripts`  whether `scripts.author` matches or not.

What am I doing wrong?

My data looks like this

```
{
name: "something"
scripts:[
    {author:"something", data:"data"},
    {author:"something else" data:"data2"},
    {author:"something", data:"data3"}
        ]
}
```

I'd like to get all the `scripts` where `author` matches what I give it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here for you to understand about matching in queries like this. First of all, what your were trying to do was this:

```
customer.find(
    { "name":tenantName, "scripts.author": author },
    { "scripts.$" },
    function(err,data2) {

      // work here
})
```

And that would use the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator to match the element. But the problem here is that will only match the **first** element of the array. This is covered in the documentation. The result will be like this:

```
{ "scripts" : [  {  "author" : "something",  "data" : "data" } ] }
```

If you need to match **muliple** elements, then you need to use the aggregate function in order to **filter** the array contents:

```
customer.aggregate([

    // Match just the documents you want
    { "$match": { "name": tenantName, "scripts.author": author } },

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$scripts" },

    // Match to filter just the array elements
    { "$match": { "scripts.author": author } },

    // Push back the array elements
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "scripts": { "$push": "$scripts" }
    }}

],
function(err,result) {

})
```

And the results there will be the **two** elements that match "something" as the `author`.

Why all of this? Well there is the limitation on what can be done with projection that was mentioned. But the main reason is that you are **not** matching elements in the **array**, but you are matching the **document** that "contains" the *matching* elements in the array.

So if you really want to filter the results, this is how you do it.